# Throttled speed to specific IP address from within home WiFi only

Tags: apache-http-server, isp

I am experiencing a weird problem where:

- Accessing my own dedicated server at a hosting provider in France is slow between the hours of 6pm and 10pm.
- Just accessing this particular IP is slow, not everything else
- Accessing the IP from my phone for example is fine

I called my ISP and they say they don't block or throttle anything. I also reset my router completely but the problem persists.

I can download files via ssh inside my server no problem and at full speed. I contacted my server provider, they ran some tests and they get full speed.

What can I do? How can I find out what is causing this issue?

EDIT: I access the server directly via IP and use WebDav. I also try to move a file to a public folder and download it in the browser. Same slow download speed.

I just reset all my Apache config and just added the WebDav part. Still the same slow access.

UPDATE:

- PING from phone: 44ms
- PING from Computer within WiFi: 32ms

Comment: Hm ..
Do you mean directly accessing the IP or domain resolution is slow ? 
Can you validate and confirm the slowness with ping on phone or using some other ISP? Also Could it be possible to test it using phone's WiFi hot-spot ? What about phone using  connection from router? 
You could also try to use traceroute to see if there is any bottleneck appearing. 
Are there any heavy cron jobs running on the server during that time? Could that be that it's a busy time in the dedicated server during that time or this time frame is a busy time in France (in case you are not in same timezone)?

Comment: Any CRON jobs running at that time?

Comment: No CRON jobs running. Download to phone with around 100Mbit/s when phone is not in WiFi. With Computer in WiFi 5Mbit/s. PING from phone 44ms and PING from computer 32ms.